# What is returned by scipy.io.wavefile.read()?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, scipy

I have never worked with audio before.

For a monophonic wav file read() returns an 1-D array of integers. What do these integers represent? Are they the frequencies? If not how do I use them to get the frequencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wavfile.read()` returns two things:

data: This is the data from your wav file which is the amplitude of the audio taken at even intervals of time.

sample rate: How many of those intervals make up one second of audio.